# Is screen share annotation supported with Agora WebSDK?

Tags: agora.io

I am trying to implement a platform where I can interact with somebody and should be able to annotate on the shared screen. I am exploring agora, normal 1-1 call with screen sharing seems to be working, just wanted to know if the annotation feature is there or not. I tried searching on the agora docs, could not find any.
Please share the useful links

Answer (score 0):

Screen annotation isn't supported by the Web SDK yet. You can either make a feature request or build it on top of the screenshare yourself. You can use an HTML canvas overlay on top of the screen share to draw the annotations and send the draw data to the remote users using Agora RTM.